# How to define a proper mongoose schema?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is this a proper way to define it?

```
const mongoose = require("../database");
 
// create a schema
var userschema =new mongoose.Schema({
            name: String,
            password: String,
            email:String
        });
 
var userModel=mongoose.model('users',userSchema);
 
module.exports = mongoose.model("Users", userModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Please Try In This Way

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    const User = mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          default: "",
          trim: true,
        },
        email: {
          type: String,
          default: "",
          trim: true,
          validate: {
            validator: async function (email) {
              const user = await this.constructor.findOne({ email });
              if (user) {
                if (this.id === user.id) {
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            },
            message: (props) => "This email is already in use",
          },
          required: [true, "User email required"],
        },
        password: {
          type: String,
          default: "",
          trim: true,
          select: false,
        },
        mobile: {
          type: String,
          default: "",
          trim: true,
        },
        experience: {
          type: String,
          default: "",
          trim: true,
        },
        agree: {
          type: Array,
          default: "",
          trim: true,
        },
        status: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1,
        },
        type: {
          type: String,
        },
        isDelete: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
      {
        timestamps: { createdAt: "createdAt", updatedAt: "updatedAt" },
      }
    );
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```